# Python - trying to get specific words as output however receiving error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, data-science

Trying to match the skills as a patter and apply a groupby function however receiving as unhashable list.

```
Tec_skills=['MS SQL Server', 'Oracle','Machine Learning', 'Artificial Intelligence', 'Deep Neural Networks', 
        'Convolutional Neural Network', 'Sklearn Libraries', 'Keras','Tensor flow', 'SQL', 'C#','NoSQL',' Docker',
       'Python','Shell','SQL/PLSQL','PLSQL','R','C','C++','AWS','Neural Networks,','CNN','RNN','Linear/Logistic Regression', 
        'Ensemble Trees, Gradient','Boosted trees, Bagging, Random forest','Time series','Data Visualization','Sentiment Analysis',
       'Docker & Kubernetes','Classification','clustering','supervised','unsupervised']
def tech_skills(text):
    word_tokens=word_tokenize(text)
    filtered_stop_word = [word for word in word_tokens if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    all_combinations=' '.join,everygrams(filtered_stop_word,2,3)
    #ext_skills=[]
    ext_skills=re.findall(Tec_skills,all_combinations)
    if ext_skills:
        return (ext_skills.group(0))
    return (ext_skills.group(0))

All_pdf_data_bygroup=All_pdf_data.groupby(All_pdf_data.index)


All_pdf_data_bygroup["text"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).apply(lambda x:tech_skills(x))
```

`ERROR:TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Please suggets how to resolve the issue .

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow!. it seems you miss some information for resolving the issue please make minimal reproducible example if you want better results

Comment: also there moght be an issue using the findall  function woth a lost argument. is that the case?

Comment: There's a comma between `' '.join` and `everygrams` that looks wrong. Also, you're using the `refindall()` function incorrectly.